# ejs file. Creating a card to show articles "%> <%"

Tags: mongodb, express, ejs

I am following a youtube tutorial on creating a blog using node, MongoDB, and express.

I am having difficulty understanding some stuff.

```
      <!--Creating the Article Cards-->
      <% article.forEach(article =>{ %>

      <div class="card mt-4"><%= article.title%></div>
      <% }) %>
```

here is the code

```
      %>
      <div class="card mt-4"><%= article.title%></div>
      <%
```

the area I don't understand is why there is and what " %> <% " mean as you can see above after doing the forEach.

Comment: Take a look at ejs docs https://ejs.co/#docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that is a scriplet tag that is used for the   control-flow you need to use in the `if-else` as well. Here is more for the `ejs` [ejs](https://ejs.co/)